# django update page when database field updates?

Tags: ajax, django, dajaxice

I have a results page and I am trying to work out how to auto update the page when an external database field is updated. I have seen quite a few examples but they seem to relate to PHP. I have a test that calls various APIs that can take up to an hour to complete. Once the test has completed, it will enter a success or failed message in a database field.

I already have my results page being rendered by django using template tags. I have a table and I have the field I would like to update. There are multiple fields that need update which correspond to each API test.

I have seen this site.. is this the kind of stuff to use? http://www.dajaxproject.com/ Is this an easy task to do? Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Sorry but I don't know where to start on this one.

Cheers - Oli

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to be so bold and just use the old classic page update for this purpose using javascript..

```
window.onload = setupRefresh;

function setupRefresh() {
    setTimeout("refreshPage();", 30000); // milliseconds
}

function refreshPage() {
    window.location = location.href;
}
```

Still open for options however I'm rather inexperienced in django and maybe this was too much to bite off too quickly..